# Can emacs control other programs windows?

Tags: process

I am using `start-process` to start other programs as part of my workflow. For example starting a browser to display the HTML file I am working on, or Visual Studio to debug the EXE I just compiled.

As part of the workflow I switch back to Emacs, continue my work. I do some more editing/compiling, and then have to switch back to this external program.

Does Emacs provide easy ways to manipulate those external programs beyond creating them? Can I programmatically switch to those windows using <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>, resize and move them?

I am asking specifically for Windows but it would be good to know about other OSes as well

Comment: That sort of thing is generally handled by the operating system, or window manager. With Linux, using the i3m window manager, moving and resizing windows is scriptable, and you can call those scripts from Emacs just like Emacs can call any other script or program. I don't think Emacs has any built-in features for managing this directly.

Comment: I agree with @Tyler —this is hard on Windows — but would just add that on Windows if you have any hope of doing this it would probably be via AHK (AutoHotKey). You may have to resort to a kludge of creating funcs that, instead of directly opening Visual Studio or whatever app, instead calls an AHK script that can launch and then “drive” the underlying program.